# Preventing runaway AWS Lambda function triggers

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I have a Lambda function that is triggered when a folder object -- for example,

```
67459e53-20cb-4e7d-8b7a-10e4cd165a44
```

is created in the root bucket.

Also in the root is `index.json`, the content index -- a simple array of these folders. For example, { folder1, folder2, ..., folderN }.

Every time a folder object (like above) is added, the Lambda function triggers, gets `index.json`, adds the new folder object to the JSON array, and then puts `index.json` back.

Obviously, this `createObject` event is going to trigger the *same* Lambda function.

My code, below, should *only* process the event object if it's a folder; i.e., a key object with a `/` at the end. (A stackoverflow user was kind enough to help me with this solution.)

I have tested this code locally with `lambda-local` and everything looks good. My concern is **(fear of God)** that I could have RUNAWAY EXECUTION.

I have scoured the Lambda best practices and googled for "infinite loops" and the like, but cannot find a way to ENSURE that my Lambda won't execute more than, say, 50 times per day.

Yes, I could have the Lambda that actually creates the folder also write to `index.json` but that Lambda is part of the AWS Video-on-Demand reference example, and I don't really understand it yet.

Two questions: Can I configure notifications in S3 such that it filters on a (random folder key name with a) suffix of `/` as described
[here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/NotificationHowTo.html#notification-how-to-filtering)? And/Or how can I configure this Lambda in the console to absolutely prevent runaway execution?

```
// dependencies
var async = require('async');
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
var util = require('util');

// constants
const VOD_DEST_FOLDER = 'my-triggering-bucket'; //not used bc part of event object
const CONTENT_INDEX_FILENAME = 'index.json';

// get reference to S3 client
var s3 = new AWS.S3();

exports.handler = async (event) => {
  try {
    console.log('Event', JSON.stringify(event));

    // Bucket name.
    const triggerBucket = event.Records[0].s3.bucket.name;

    // New folder key added.
    const newKey = event.Records[0].s3.object.key;

    // Add newKey to content index ONLY if it is a folder object. If any other object
    // is added in the bucket root then it won't result in new write.
    if (newKey.indexOf('/') > -1) {

      // Get existing data.
      let existing = await s3.getObject({
        Bucket: triggerBucket,
        Key: CONTENT_INDEX_FILENAME
      }).promise();

      // Parse JSON object.
      let existingData = JSON.parse(existing.Body);

      // Get the folder name.
      const folderName = newKey.substring(0, newKey.indexOf("/"));

      // Check if we have an array.
      if (!Array.isArray(existingData)) {
        // Create array.
        existingData = [];
      }

      existingData.push(folderName);

      await s3.putObject({
        Bucket: triggerBucket,
        Key: CONTENT_INDEX_FILENAME,
        Body: JSON.stringify(existingData),
        ContentType: 'application/json'
      }).promise();

      console.log('Added new folder name ' + folderName);

      return folderName;

     } else {
         console.log('Not a folder.');
         return 'Ignored';
     }
  }
  catch(err) {
    return err;
  }
};
```

Comment: Are you worried about race conditions? If two folders are created around the same time, this lambda could fire twice and only one of the two folders might be added to your index.json file in s3.

Comment: Good point. But, no... at this time no chance of this happening! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can configure the [S3 notifications with key name filtering](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/NotificationHowTo.html#notification-how-to-filtering). Here's a [step by step guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/user-guide/enable-event-notifications.html#enable-event-notifications-how-to) on how to do it in the web console. I think if you add a `/` suffix filter to the notification that triggers your Lambda, you will achieve your goal.

Comment: Nope. Appears that doesn't work. I can't specify a suffix of `/`. The Lambda never triggers. And when I remove that filter, the Lambda fires repeatedly; presumably with every putObject of my index.json. It keeps adding the newly created video folder name to the JSON array. So, had to delete the S3 event notification. I'm not sure why it does this since the local Lambda test ran once.